# How prove this series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n+1}+a_{n})$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

let $$0\le a_{n}<\dfrac{1}{n},n=1,2,3,\cdots $$

prove or disprove 
(1)$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n+1}+a_{n})$$ is convergent?

(2)
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^na_{n}$$ is convergent?

I fell this is true,can you someone have counter-examples? Thank you

Comment: Take $a_n = \frac{1}{2n}$

Comment: What if we take $a_n=\frac{1}{n+1}$ ?

Answer (score 4):

It is false.

$$a_n = \frac{1}{2n}$$

The sum is "almost" the harmonic series and it diverges

Answer (score 1):

This may be false, if close enough to the upper bound.

Consider
$a_n = \frac 1{2n}$, $n>0$.

$$
a_n + a_{n+1} = \frac 1{2n} + \frac 1{2n+2} > \frac 2{2n+2} = \frac 1{n+1}
$$Hence, $$
\sum a_n + a_{n+1} = \infty
$$

Comment: I know that it's not the harmonic series, but $a_n + a_{n+1} - h_n$ has a limit equal to 0 right ?

Comment: yes, but I don't see your point.

Comment: Pas hyper important mais elles sont équivalentes donc ont la même nature. C'était par rapport à ton commentaire sur le fait que c'était pas la série harmonique, c'était juste un abus de langage !

Comment: attentiom tout de même, que la différence tende vers 0 est une chose, l'équivalence en est une autre. Par exemple, $[2^{-n} + 1/n] - [2^{-n}]$ tend vers 0 , et pourtant les deux séries n'ont pas la même nature !

Comment: Oui, oui y'avait pas de lien entre la limite à 0 et l'équivalence, c'était juste le temps de me remettre les idées en place ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just take $a_n = \frac{1}{2 n}$. If your series converges, it serves as a bound for the series
$$
\sum_{n \ge 1} a_n = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{n}
$$
As this one doesn't converge, neither does yours.

Answer (score 0):

For the second one, the series is convergent, since $0 \leq a_n \leq \frac{1}{n}$ and therefore $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty } a_n = 0$ and by the alternating series test the series converges.

Comment: Alternating series test works only when $a_n$ is monotone decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

For the second one, $a_n=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2n},&n\text{ is even,}\\0,&n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$ becomes a counterexample. Check it.